# Please rename [uwp-community-toolkit] to [windows-community-toolkit]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Could anyone please help us rename the [uwp-community-toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp-community-toolkit) tag to [windows-community-toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-community-toolkit)?

Please refer to this [post](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/05/02/announcing-a-new-name-for-the-uwp-community-toolkit-windows-community-toolkit/) for reasons behind the name change.